# How to define an environment that begins with a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, nodes

Please see the following definition:

```
     \tikzstyle{boxStyle} = [draw=blue!80, fill=blue!9, very thick,
        rectangle, rounded corners=3mm, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=15pt]
     \tikzstyle{boxTitleStyle} =[fill=blue!80, rectangle, rounded corners=2mm,
        text=white, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=7pt, left=10pt]

     \newcommand{\textBox}[2] {
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node [boxStyle]  (box) {\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}};
       \node[boxTitleStyle] at (box.north east) {#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
     }
```

Now I want to covert it as an environment:

```
 \newenvironment{textBox}[1]
  {\begin{tikzpicture}\node [boxStyle]  (box) {\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}}}
  {\end{minipage};\node[boxTitleStyle] at (box.north east) {#1};\end{tikzpicture}}
```

or,

```
 \newenvironment{textBox}[1]
  {\begin{tikzpicture}\node [boxStyle]  (box) \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}}
  {\end{minipage};\node[boxTitleStyle] at (box.north east) {#1};\end{tikzpicture}}
```

are not true, any suggestions?

Comment: You might skip directly to [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed) package to have similar constructs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start a *node* in the `\begin` part and finish it in the `\end` part using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  boxStyle/.style={draw=blue!80, fill=blue!9, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners=3mm, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=15pt},
  boxTitleStyle/.style={fill=blue!80, rectangle, rounded corners=2mm,
    text=white, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=7pt, left=10pt},
}

\newenvironment{textBox}[1]{%
  \def\title{#1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [boxStyle] (box)
    \bgroup\minipage{0.5\textwidth}%
}{
    \endminipage%
    \egroup;
    \node[boxTitleStyle] at (box.north east) {\title};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{textBox}{Hello}
This is some text that goes in the minipage
\end{textBox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't start a node in the `\begin` part and finish it in the `\end` part. But the `environ` package comes to the rescue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,environ}
\tikzstyle{boxStyle} = [draw=blue!80, fill=blue!9, very thick,
  rectangle, rounded corners=3mm, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=15pt]
\tikzstyle{boxTitleStyle} =[fill=blue!80, rectangle, rounded corners=2mm,
  text=white, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=7pt, left=10pt]

\NewEnviron{textBox}[1]
 {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [boxStyle]  (box)
     {\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\BODY\end{minipage}};
    \node[boxTitleStyle] at (box.north east) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{textBox}{Hello}
This is some text that goes in the minipage
\end{textBox}

\end{document}
```

The environment's contents is absorbed and becomes the replacement text of `\BODY`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, before I register here I learn a lot from your great answers :)