# How to create an environment that embeds an environment inside a macro?

Tags: environments

Let's say I have an environment `myenvironment` and I have the following code :

```
\makebox[\length][c]{%
\begin{myenvironment}
content
\end{myenvironment}
}
```

I want to create an environment `foo` that would do the same but simply with

```
\begin{foo}{\length}
content
\end{foo}
```

I know how to pass `\length` to `foo`. The problem is the command `makebox` (or any command that would delimit `myenvironment`). I attempted this naive approach :

```
\newenvironment{foo}{%
\makebox[\length][c]{
\begin{myenvironment} 
}{%
\end{myenvironment}}
}
```

which of course doesn't work because you can't have `{` and `}` by themselves in a block.

I found this similar question but I am not sure it applies to my problem: [How to define an environment that begins with a node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/how-to-define-an-environment-that-begins-with-a-node) . And I don't really understand the validated answer.

So how would I go about to create the environment `foo` ? I would prefer a solution without using the package `environ`. If useful for a solution, I am using the `xparse` and `etoolbox` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is using `lrbox`:

```
\newsavebox{\foobox}

\newenvironment{foo}
 {% start
  \begin{lrbox}{\foobox}%
  \begin{myenvironment}%
 }
 {% end
  \end{myenvironment}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[\length][c]{\usebox{\foobox}}%
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and now I know how to save stuff inside boxes.